# Join two tables in controller

Tags: php, laravel

Sheep migration

```
Schema::create('sheeps', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->integer('corral_id')->unsigned()->nullable();

    $table->foreign('corral_id')->references('id')->on('corrals');
});
```

Corral only has `name` field. I want to show corrals with sheep. I can go through each sheep and check `corral_id` in front-end and place to related corral. But I want to do it in the backend, so I should get corral with sheep there.

```
public function index():CorralResourceCollection
{
    return new CorralResourceCollection(Corral::paginate());
}
```

Comment: Maybe `Corral::with('sheeps')->paginate()`?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do a SQL join, or would just joining two collections work?

In below example, I have two tables, named dogs and cats. I can create a collection of all their names easily by doing (try this in Tinker):

```
use MyCoolApp\Models\Dog;
use MyCoolApp\Models\Cat;

$all_my_pets = Dog::get()->pluck('name');
$all_my_pets->concat(Cat::get()->pluck('name'));
```